# Get List View of data received from web service in Android

Tags: android, web-services, visual-studio-2008

I am new to Android . I have created a web service in Visual Studio 2008. This is my web service code [http://pastebin.com/QHqL6bNx] . I have also written an Android code to call the web service from my emulator..Here is the Android code [http://pastebin.com/rDhkRTsQ] . My problem is that I want to display the data that I get from my web service in a ListView with a checkbox at the side of it . How to do that ?

Can anyone help me develop the code for it ? What changes should I do in my present code?

Thanks

Comment: you mean you want to put checkbox besides of every list item, right?

Comment: Hello :D as any web request and since we are using mobile you have to think that a request can take 1s or 2 minutes depend on connection. So first try to make a list the way you want with simples exmple than serach for painless threathing to make the request.

Comment: @Paresh Mayani- yes I wanna do that only.. How should I modify my current code then ?

Comment: @subspider : ok ya my database contains around 50 items ..so I need to think of a better strategy for that .. I have heard of NFC (near field communication ) , do u think I can use it over here? Also till 5 mins will be fine for me...but more than that would be not desirable

Comment: @Parth_90 hi look i currently using services with 250 items and my rating is 2,5 seconds. To make a good thing in my point of view use Serialization and Deserailization you take look at these sample http://sharpertutorials.com/serialization/

Comment: @subspider: Yes I saw it. I wanted something like this only. Thanks a lot for the link !! :-) Also , btw I wanted to do one more thing which is to send the checked or ticked items back to another database via the same web service, can it be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the response of the server. I recommend to encode the output of your web service to be in `JSON` or `XML` format, because its quick and easy to parse that kind of response.

Comment: and how am I suppose to do that ? My output is in XML. I see it in my browser when I run the web service . Can u tell me how to parse XML then ? any extra code I have to write then ?

Comment: Yep, you need to write some code for the parsing (see google for more examples :P ) `You parse -> fill the ArrayList you are using for the listview -> pass data to the Adapter you are using -> populate the listview`

Comment: I tried Googling a bit and all I could find was info related to a SAX parser ..is it what your talking about as regards to parsing ?

Comment: You need to interpret the XML output you get for the response. That's why parsing.